# Living organisms with properties similar to both plants and animals?

Tags: evolution, zoology, botany

Is there any example of currently living organisms that shows close resemblance to both being a plant and an animal?

What is the plant with the closest possible resemblance to animals, and
What is the animal with the closest possible resemblance to plants?

Comment: It should be stressed that any resemblence found would be due to convergent evolution: natural selection leading to similar solutions from  diverged evolutionary histories.

Comment: I have added important new information in a new answer to the proposed duplicate question.